# Can ps -ef omit specific owners of processes?

Tags: shell

I'm learning how to write unix/linux commands. Is there any way that I can use a ps -ef to view processes, but have the command ignore the owner when it's root?

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore the owner when it's `root`?" Are you asking, "how do I list only processes that are not owned by `root`?", or something else?

Answer (score 1):

With the `procps-ng` implementation of `ps` (as typically found on non-embedded Linux-based systems), you can remove the `-e` option and replace it with `-N -u root` to have `ps` show you the processes that are running as any user except root:

```
ps -f -N -u root
```

You can pack `-f -N` together as `-Nf` or `-fN` to shorten the command line (similar to how you pack `-e -f` together into `-ef`)

Essentially you're replacing the option that tells `ps` to select every process (`-e`) with an option that tells `ps` to select only the processes running as the root user (`-u root`), and adding the negation option (`-N`), so `ps` selects all the processes except the ones running as root.  The `-u` option can take a list of users, so if you want to filter out the root or daemon processes, you can use `ps -f -N -u root,daemon`.

The `ps` man page groups options based on their function (simple process selection, process selection by list, output format control, etc), so the `-N` option can be used to negate/invert the action of the other process selection options.  For example, `ps -f -p 123` would select only process id `123`, but `ps -f -N -p 123` will show all the processes that are not process id `123`.