# Does the p(rocess)s(napshot) support service exclude?

Tags: linux, ps

I want to use ps to show all processes except the some of them - exclude info about `ssh` or `kthreadd` processess.

Am I able to indicate processes I want to exclude?

The only supported way for now - non ps - is `grep -v`.

Comment: Interesting! Didn't know that's what `ps` stood for. Is that a canonical thing?

Comment: Some `ps` implementations can exclude processes from the output, but the exclusions might not cover your use case.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/718950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Unix in general and Linux in this concrete case don't make such distinctions about processes, "service" or "not a service"

Filtering the output using grep seems quite reasonable, so I'd stick with it.

Comment: Thank you for an answer and advices.
Have a good day :)